# Check if element appended already w/ jQuery

Tags: jquery

I need to modify a function. When a condition is met an element is appended. I need to add a check to see if this element has been already added, because it can be only added just once.

```
function checkBox()
{
 if ($("#myBox").find('.myClass').length == 0)
 {
   $("#myBox").append(
        $('<a href="" id="newBox">click</a>')
   );   
 } 
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
function checkBox() {
    if (!$("#myBox").find('.myClass').length) {
        $("#myBox").append('<a href="" id="newBox">click</a>');
    }
}
```

### Check working example http://jsfiddle.net/nYbTv/

Comment: That's great, and I agree this is the correct way to append but I still need to work in a check into the function to see if this was already appended or not. Thanks.

Comment: @santa In your example you have `find('.myClass')`. Why are you looking for myClass. Are you appending `a` to `myClass`.

Comment: No, this class is assigned to draggable divs that resign in #myBox. The new item is appended as soon as the last .myClass is dragged outside of this area. The problem currently is that every time a div with .myClass is dragged, once all of them are out from #myBox, another <a href> is appended...

Comment: @santa The example i gave you does just that. It checks for the existence of `myClass` if myClass does not exist then `a` gets appended to `#myBox`

Comment: OK, got it. Here's my final version: function checkBox() {
    if (!$("#myBox").find('.myClass').length && !$("#myBox").find('a').length) {
        $("#myBox").append('<a href="" id="newBox">click</a>');
    }
}

Comment: @Hussein in my case, i need to work with classes, what should I do?

Answer (score 3):

```
function checkBox()
{
 if ($("#myBox").find('#newBox').length == 0)
 {
   $("#myBox").append(
        $('<a href="" id="newBox">click</a>')
   );   
 } 
}
```

Also note that when passing a serialised HTML string to `append()`, you don't have to rewrap it with the jQuery object.

Comment: Why are you appending an object. `<a>` doesn't need to be wrapped with jQuery.

Comment: @Hussein See edit. I just copied the OP's example. BTW, it won't *not* work either.

Comment: OP is wrong wrapping `a` with jQuery. It's better to correct him rather then going along with his mistake.

Comment: @Hussein Well, depends on what you call wrong. It's unnecessary, but it won't stop it from working. I wouldn't do it personally.